# Update model from database shows only newer .NET frameworks

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4, connection-string, updatemodel

I have a winforms application that is using .NET 4. I created another database that has the exact same structure as the old one, and now I have to change the connection string in my Data Model to point to the new database.

If I change the connection string in the App.config file and then in the designer press Update  Model From Database it doesn't show any connections(that's fine), but when I try to add a new connection it only lets me choose Entity Framework version 5.0, as shown in the picture bellow:

[image]

The problem is that I need version 4. I searched a lot on the Internet for someone with a similar problem, but I couldn't find anything.. What do I do wrong?

Comment: How did you change the connection string, changing the `data source` and/or `initial catalog` part, or something else?

Comment: @YuliamChandra, I've changed just the `initial catalog`. Both databases are on the same server. But it's weird, I've done it before and it was working just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the entity framework version by typing this command in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package EntityFramework -version 4.3.0`

After that, in the update wizard I was able to select Entity Framework 4.3.0.0 and it worked like a charm.

This is the link that helped me:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn440683